# <p:ajax> or <f:ajax> inside table with nested <c:forEach> table

Tags: ajax, jsf, foreach, html-table, jsf-2.2

In relation with [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289847/pajax-update-cell-or-row-update-inside-pf-subtable) I still have the following issue: process a selectOneRadio value in one column of a table to update a value in another column of the same table.

In my original question where I tried it with a datatable and a subtable, after lametaweb's suggestion and as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637213/pajax-update-inside-nested-components) did not give successful result because of the following behaviour: "`tabView1:1:form1:mainTable:0:subTable1:0:panel`" (without correct cliendId) seen in the HTML, I manually built the table with nested `<c:forEach>` to reconstruct the same.

But neither  nor  are updating the value in the table. And Here is an example of the actual clientId in the HTML: `form0:j_idt71:0`.

```
<h:form id="form0">

<table id="table0">

        <c:forEach var="head" items="#{subTableView.getAllHeaders('tabName')}">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputLabel style="bold" value="#{head.name}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <c:forEach var="row" items="#{head.questions}">

                <tr>
                    <td width="300" height="33">
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{row.question}" />
                    </td>

                    <td width="500">

                        <p:selectOneRadio id="mainSelect" value="#{row.select1}" >

                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="#{row.responseOfYes}" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="#{row.responseOfNo}" />/>

                        <p:ajax update="display"                                                                                        listener="#{subTableView.updateSecond(row.select1)}"/>

                        </p:selectOneRadio>

                    </td>

                    <td width="600">

                            <h:outputLabel id="display" value="#{row.select1}" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </c:forEach>

</table>
```

Comment: `<h:outputLabel id="display" binding="#{display}" value="#{row.select1}" />` `<p:ajax update="#{display.clientId}"`/>. (You are unnecessarily using `<h:outputLabel>` for displaying text. Its sole purpose is different. Use `<h:outputText>` instead). Additionally, insist upon using `<p|h:dataTable>`.

Comment: @Tiny: Thanks, not working neither with binding nor with `<h:outputText>`. Is the `clientId` inside `<p:ajax update="#{display.clientId}"/>` to be used as-is? or shall I refer it to a tag?

Comment: Try displaying the outcome of `#{display.clientId}` somewhere and compare **the generated** `id` of `<h:outputLabel>` (or `<h:outputText>` whatever you are using). They should be the same. If the problem still persists then, it should persist somewhere else - it should be caused by something else.

Comment: @Tiny how would you display the Id of `<h:outputLabel>`?

Comment: Just do `#{display.clientId}` inside the table (the inner most `<c:forEach>`) somewhere just for the purpose of testing (and then remove it once done).

Comment: @Tiny: I did I have something like form0:j_idt188. But what should I compare this with?

Comment: The generated `id` of `<h:outputLabel>` or `<h:outputText>` whatever you are using. Do "View page source" on the target browser but I doubt the problem should persist somewhere else. Check also for any possible JavaScript error on the browser console (press F12 (Google Chrome)).

Comment: @Tiny: You know what's interesting: there is nothing! I have the column `<td> </td>` empty. I opened the developer tools: I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Awkward. What JSF/PrimeFaces version do you use? An empty `<td>` with no corresponding `<label>` (corresponding to `<h:outputLabel>`) or `<span>` (corresponding to `<h:outputText>`)? Are you exactly doing this the same way as shown in the question or changed the way to use a `<p|h:dataTable>`?

Comment: @Tiny: Yes sure Iam doing the same way by putting it inside a <td> </td> tag. Yes no label is displayed except for the last row: with the binding I lost the row.select1 data. Iam using JSF 2.2, with Wildfly 9.0.1 and PF 5.3. I have the following lines: `<p:ajax update="#{display.clientId}" ...` and `<h:outputLabel id="display" binding="#{display}" value="#{row.select1}" />`